# Plotly: How to change legend item shape from line to box or circle in a line chart?

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I want to change the item shape of my legend from line to any other appealing shape like a box or a circle.
Below is my chart. You can see the legend item is showing a colored line. It is not very appealing.

How do I change the shape of the legend item without changing the chart type?

[image: my plot-line legend]

Below is the example of a desired item shape for my legend.

[image: desired-plot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best option to *hopefully* make your legend symbols a bit more visually appealing without messing up the figure traces as well seems to be:

```
fig.layout.legend.itemsizing = 'constant'
```

Which will give you the following legend with items that at least look a bit more like a box or rectangle instead of a line:

[image]

Instead of this:

[image]

#### Some details:

The shape of the legend by default reflects the shape of your trace. That also goes for size and shape of a marker symbol. So if you build a plot like this:

[image]

Then you can always change the way the legend looks through:

```
fig.data[0].mode = 'markers+lines'
fig.data[0].marker.symbol = 'diamond'
fig.data[0].marker.size = 12
```

But the problem is that this goes for the figure traces as well as you can see here:

[image]

And I've made a few attempts on setting a marker symbol and then removing the marker for the traces to *hopefully* retain the marker in the legend. But that doesn't work. And I think we're all better off for it. So that leaves you with my initial suggestion.

#### Complete code:

```
# imports
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

# data
df = px.data.stocks()
df = df.drop(['AMZN', 'AAPL', 'MSFT', 'FB'], axis = 1)
colors = px.colors.qualitative.T10

# plotly
fig = px.line(df, 
                 x = 'date',
                 y = [c for c in df.columns if c != 'date'],
                 template = 'plotly_dark',
                 color_discrete_sequence = colors,
                 title = 'Stocks', 
             )
fig.data[0].mode = 'markers+lines'
fig.data[0].marker.symbol = 'diamond'
fig.data[0].marker.size = 12

fig.layout.legend.itemsizing = 'constant'
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be too late, but I found a hacky work-around to customize the legend shapes of a line graph by using the ff configuration:

```
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4],
    y=[10, 15, 13, 17],
    name = 'trace 1',
    # Set the legendgroup per trace. 
#   Use this legendgroup with the corresponding shape so clicking the shape's legend will toggle the trace.
    legendgroup = 'trace 1',
    marker = dict(color='firebrick'),
    # Don't show the legend for the trace so only the shape's legend is visible.
    showlegend = False,
))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4],
    y=[16, 5, 11, 9],
    name = 'trace 2',
    legendgroup = 'trace 2',
    marker = dict(color='royalblue'),
    showlegend = False,
))

fig.add_shape(
    name = 'trace 1',
#   The shape should match the trace's legend group so it will toggle the shape and the trace as a group.
  legendgroup = 'trace 1',
#    Show the shape's legend.
  showlegend = True,
  type = 'rect',
#    For sanity, render the shape behind the lines.
#    But this shouldn't be necessary because the shape will never get plotted on the graph. See the xn configuration below.
  layer = 'below',
#    If you don't want a border around your legend's symbol, set the line.width to 0.
  line = dict(width = 0),
#    The fillcolor should match the trace's marker/line color.
  fillcolor = 'firebrick',
#    Set the plot points of the shape to 0 so it won't be rendered on the graph.
  x0 = 0,
  y0 = 0,
  x1 = 0,
  y1 = 0,
)

fig.add_shape(
    name = 'trace 2',
  legendgroup = 'trace 2',
  showlegend = True,
  type = 'rect',
  layer = 'below',
  line = dict(width = 0),
  fillcolor = 'royalblue',
  x0 = 0,
  y0 = 0,
  x1 = 0,
  y1 = 0,
)
```

You can see it in action here: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/goofy-bassi-3xls2j?file=%2Fmain.py%3A2%2C1

**Gist**

The main configuration properties here are:

- `legendgroup`- which groups traces/shapes into one so when a legend is clicked, it will not only toggle the trace/shape it belongs to, but it will also toggle the others within the same group.
- `shapes` - since it appears that plotly bases the legend symbol on the marker of the plot, the shape you define will also be used as the legend symbol of that shape.