# Customize plotly legend lines to square

Tags: python, plotly

I would like to change legend symbol from line to square. example code as below:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

def save_fig(fig,pngname):
    fig.write_image(pngname,format="png",width=600,height=400, scale=1)
    print("[[%s]]"%pngname)
    return

df = px.data.stocks()
print(df.columns)
df = df[['date','AMZN', 'AAPL']]

fig = go.Figure()
for name in df.columns:
    if name == 'date': continue
    trace = go.Scatter(
        x = df['date'],
        y = df[name],
        name=name,
    )
    fig.add_trace(trace)
        
save_fig(fig,"./demo.png")
```

What's proper way to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on top of @*PenguinBlues*' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77241926/16120011) :

```
fig = go.Figure()

for name, color in zip(
    df.columns.difference(["date"], sort=False),
    fig.layout.template.layout.colorway
):
    trace = go.Scatter(
        x = df["date"],
        y = df[name],
        name=name,
        legendgroup=name,
        marker=dict(color=color),
        showlegend = False,
    )
    
    fig.add_trace(trace)   

    fig.add_shape(
        name=name,
        legendgroup=name,
        showlegend=True,
        type="rect",
        line=dict(width=0),
        fillcolor=color,
        y0=0, y1=0,
    )
    
fig.update_xaxes(range=[df["date"].min(), df["date"].max()])
fig.update_yaxes(range=[df.describe().loc["min"].min(),
                        df.describe().loc["max"].max()])
        

fig.show();
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: Thanks, not sure why I get error: ValueError: Invalid property specified for object of type plotly.graph_objs.layout.Shape: 'legendgroup'

Comment: [I'm using the latest 5.18.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeqUa.png).

Comment: mime is 5.14.1, I try pip3 install plotly on ubuntu, but still the same version.

Comment: Try with `pip install -U plotly` or `pip install plotly==5.18.0`.

Comment: Great, it works fine now! thanks. what's the reason assign color to trace, by default value not work for this case?

Comment: I had to assign specific colors to the traces in order to do the same with the shapes. Otherwise, the squares will have the same color. Feel free to modify the code if you can think of a solution ;)